# Why doesn't Swift use getter and setter for properties as much as Java or C#?

Tags: swift, getter-setter, computed-properties

Q1: I am from Java/C# background and learning Swift right now. When I write java or C# code, for every property within the class, I need to write getter and setter. However, I found that we didn't write getter and setter so much in swift. I am curious about why it is.

Q2: I know there are two kinds of properties, stored and computed properties. It seems like we only need to set the getter or setter for computed properties. Is that true?

Comment: **Ensure the title *matches* the problem**. This will avoid many reactionary down-votes. The actual issue and title currently have no useful relation. Also, include *actual error indicators*, including error messages or supportive output.

Comment: I wrote an article on exactly this question, from a Java perspective: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java historically had different syntax for direct property access versus a method call that gets the value (a "getter"). Since you might someday want to override a property with a method, for consistency it is common to create a method in all cases.

Swift avoids this problem by having the same syntax for direct property access and "getters" (computed properties). This means you can change your mind later without impacting callers, and so there is no reason to create a method "just in case."

A computed property is *defined* as one with a "getter" (a `get` method) in Swift.

Comment: Syntactic similarity isn't enough, it's important also necessary that stored and computer properties both have the same ABI, so that the callers don't have to change. Lucky, Swift does that (though I think there was some internal attribute to allow direct access, IDR)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Is there a case in Swift or Java's history where syntactic similarity wasn't sufficient? Before ABI stability, you had to build everything together, so it didn't matter. Since ABI stability, "luckily, Swift does that," so it doesn't matter. Is there a case where this distinction is important to the question at hand (true, though it is?)

Comment: I toss that in just to illustrate that the "problem" in java isn't simply a matter of different syntax between methods and properties. If Java hypothetically added a static-rewrite to turn `target.field` into `target.getField()`, but still allowed direct ivar access, they would still have a problem that needs to be solved via this defensive, explicit ivar hiding and getter/setter writing.